# Datepicker for Angular 4

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am trying to add datepicker to Angular 4 based application.
I tried to use ng2-datepicker. After install ng2-datepicker via npm I imported module like this:

```
import {DatePickerModule} from 'ng2-datepicker-bootstrap';
```

But webpack says can not find DatePickerModule.
And I've tried to use ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker, I imported it in app.module.ts like this:

```
import {A2Edatetimepicker} from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    A2Edatetimepicker
  ]
})
```

and webpack says:

> ERROR in A2Edatetimepicker is not an NgModule

I am not sure what's wrong. Is there any cool datepicker for Angular 4? Or Did I do something wrong?
Please, help me to fix this problem.

Comment: This second datetimepicker you have mentioned does not work with Angular 4. Look this issue at its github: https://github.com/atais/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/issues/15

Comment: @Christian Benseler - Thanks for your response. But it's fixed after that. Please check here:
https://github.com/atais/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/pull/19
Do you have any suggestion about datepicker for Angular 4?

Comment: Have you considered just using angular-material2? Their datepicker is great. And they have so many other modules to use. AND, if you wanted, you could technically only use their datepicker and nothing else, although then that might be a bit of a waste.

Comment: Thanks. @AnilSingh, I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run

```
npm install ng2-datepicker --save
```

then in your root module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgDatepickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgDatepickerModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this npm package. It allows you to just simply add a directive to your input or element and is designed for both single and date range.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Input Date" date-picker (dateselected)="dateSelected($event)" />
```

[date picker directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-picker-directive)